# How to retry a handled failure in an AWS Step Function

Tags: aws-step-functions

I've got a step function that essentially does the following:

1. `[START]` Run a Lambda to Start an Athena Query, Return QueryID
2. `[POLL]` Run a Lambda to check the status of the Query, Return Status Info
3. Choice State.

   - If `STATUS = SUCCESS` -> `[PROCESS_RESULTS]`
   - If `STATUS = RUNNING` -> Wait 30 seconds, `[POLL]`
   - If `STATUS = FAILED` -> `[FAILURE_STEP]`

`STATUS = FAILED` isn't like the Lambda failed, it returned a proper result, but that result was to say the query failed. I've been seeing more "Query exhausted resources at this scale" errors on Athena lately, but they almost always work the second time around. I'd like to set it up to retry `[START]` with a pause and exponential back-off as defined in the Step Functions docs, similar to this:

```
   "Retry": [ {
      "ErrorEquals": [ "ErrorA", "ErrorB" ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 1,
      "BackoffRate": 2.0,
      "MaxAttempts": 2
   },
```

But this seems to only apply to real *errors*, as in exceptions. Is there a way to implement this based on a technically non-error result?

Comment: Can your lambda throw an exception for such non-error results?

Comment: I guess it could, but I'd still need the error to go back to a previous step, not retry the current one. Any way to do that?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's easy to implement manually though by passing required parameters to lambda and lambda can increment them on each iteration. You can have a choice and a wait state to handle maxAttempts and the delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another Choice state to the flow:

```
States:
  start_long_running_query:
    Type: Task
    Resource:
      Fn::GetAtt: [StartLongRunningQueryLambdaFunction, Arn]
    Next: wait_query_execution
  wait_query_execution:
    Type: Wait
    Seconds: 2
    Next: get_query_status
  get_query_status:
    Type: Task
    Resource:
      Fn::GetAtt: [GetLongRunningQueryStatusLambdaFunction, Arn]
    Next: check_query_status
  check_query_status:
    Type: Choice
    Default: wait_query_execution # RUNNING
    Choices:
      - Or:
          - Variable: "$.AthenaQueryStatusInformation.QueryState"
            StringEquals: FAILED
          - Variable: "$.AthenaQueryStatusInformation.QueryState"
            StringEquals: CANCELLED
        Next: maybe_retry
      - Variable: "$.AthenaQueryStatusInformation.QueryState"
        StringEquals: SUCCEEDED
        Next: query_succeded
  maybe_retry:
    Type: Choice
    Default: query_failed
    Choices:
      - Variable: "$.retry"
        BooleanEquals: true
        Next: start_long_running_query
  query_failed:
    Type: Pass
    Result: "This is a fallback for failed code"
    End: true
  query_succeded:
    Type: Pass
    Result: "This is a fallback for success code"
    End: true
```

Then into your lambda script you have to handle a counter (retry_cnt) and a flag (retry) variable so that will be passed to the other steps:

```
max_retry = os.getenv('max_retry', 1)

def start_long_running_query(event, context):
    
    # Your code here...

    # initilize the counter: must be taken from event if present
    # to prevent an infinite loop.
    event["retry_cnt"] = event["retry_cnt"] if "retry_cnt" in event else 0

    return event

def get_long_running_query_status(event, context):

    # Your code here...

    if status_information['QueryState'] == 'FAILED' or status_information['QueryState'] == 'CANCELLED':
        event["retry_cnt"] = int(event["retry_cnt"]) + 1
        event["retry"] = False if event["retry_cnt"] > int(max_retry) else True
    else:
        event["retry"] = False

    return event
```